# Setting One Windows Form as the MDI Child of Another Windows Form ( Or Something Equivalent)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two windows form applications, let's call them `FormA.exe` ( the parent) and `FormB.exe` ( the child). `FormB.exe` is an application that can run alone. `FormA.exe` is another application whose one of the function is to call out `FormB.exe`.

I have source code to both of the applications, and I can modify them.

Currently whenever `FormA.exe` wants to call out `FormB.exe`, I will use `Process` class to start the `FormB.exe` process. The problem is that

1. I don't know how to pass message between these two `Form`s.
2. When `FormB.exe` gets call out from `FormA`,  it will appear to user as *another* application, independent of `FormA.exe`, but I want it to appear as a single application under `FormA`, with `FormB` as a MDI child.
3. `FormB` itself is a MDI. So if I load it as a MDI, I will get this error `System.ArgumentException: Form cannot be both an MDI child and MDI parent`.
4. If I don't load as MDI, then my `FormB` cannot function as normal. In other words, the whole purpose of `FormA` is lost.

Is there any other way---besides setting `FormB` as the MDI child to `FormA`-- to make one winform app entirely contained inside another, and make them communicating with each other?

Comment: the better way to do this is to put both forms in the same process which you can do since you have the code

Comment: @David, that's a tremendous amount of work.

Comment: maybe a lot of work but at least there is the prospect of success

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Noel

There are many ways to achieve what you are trying. One way to do this is using `System.Reflection`

like this in formA

```
 Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("WindowsApplication1.exe");
        Form frm = a.CreateInstance("WindowsApplication1.FormB") as Form;
        frm.MdiParent = this;
        frm.Show();
```

Comment: @Subhash, but how are you going to pass messages between `FormA` and `FormB` ?

Comment: @Conditional Change again there are several ways but the way i am convenient is implementing Interface 
Like 
`IMdiParent formA=this.parent as IMdiParent` 
and 
`IChild formB=frm as IChild`

Comment: @Subhash, hmm, your code is not working because the `FormB` itself is a MDI form, see question updated.

Comment: @Conditional Change you can change the 'IsMdiContainer' property at runtime at any time

Comment: @Subhash, I tested already; if I changed that `IsMdiContainer` at runtime, then `FormB` will become a non MDI, which will affect the functionality of it.

Comment: why do you want the FormB to be the child of FormA. just `Show` or or `ShowDialog` it.

Comment: @Subhash, as mentioned; this is because I don't want them to appear independent of each other

Comment: I think what you are looking for can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/AppControl.aspx)

Comment: @Conditional Change did you got your answer from my previous comment

Comment: @Subhash, the solution you linked didn't even work on sample-- for example, if you click on the back button of the IE control, it won't even work.

Comment: try this. this will definitely work [Applicationhost](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/applicationhost.aspx)

Comment: @Conditional Change did you got your answer from my previous comment

Comment: @Subhash, although your previous link is good, but the problem is that the ribbon icon isn't responding at all when clicked.

Comment: @Subhash, there is a simple way to reproduce the problem: just change one of the process name to `iexplore.exe`, and try to navigate a few pages, and then try to click on the back button, you will find that the back isn't responding at all. Not sure whose problem is this.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a project reference from FormA.exe to FormB.exe and programmatically load formb as an mdi child to forma.

You can easily pass messages between them then.  FormB.exe can still be invoked on its own as an application, just keep it as an windows application rather than a windows library project.

Comment: @Noel, can you be more explicit? Are you saying that I can use [`System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/winforms/thread/ae8062a5-cd8e-4450-a4ce-d8430e93c79e)? And how do I pass message between the two apps?

Comment: You don't need to use reflection if you have the source code. You can open your VS solution for the FormA project, and add a project reference to FormB.  Then you can write code in FormA which treats FormB just as any other project in your solution.

Comment: To pass a message, you just call methods on the classes in FormB, there is nothing magic going on, its just treated as another dll.

Comment: If you are looking for some patterns for communication inside a smart client, google Event aggregator pattern.  There are various frameworks which contain an implementation you can use, ie Prism, CAB, caliburn.

Comment: @Noel, I forgot to mention that `FormB` is a MDI form, so it doesn't seem to work; see question update.

Comment: I think you are out luck, you would need to refactor FormB so that it can function both as an MDI parent to itself, and as a library to FormA.  Or put up with having it open as another form.

Comment: @Noel, even for FormB as a library to FormA is not going to solve my problem because FormB is a MDI, am I understand this correctly?

Comment: I think so, as an MDI can't have a parent, no matter how you load FormB into FormA, you aren't going to be able to set FormB's parent to FormA without changing how it works, ie by loading the forms which are children to FormB into FormA's form collection instead.  This might be trivial or incredibly invasive depending on how FormA and FormB were coded.

Comment: @Noel, OK, maybe a MDI is out of question. But you have any suggestion on how to make sure that `FormB` stays within the boundary of `FormA` and make them appear as one app?

Comment: It's difficult to know how to do this without seeing what your apps look like.  For example, you could load the menu bars from FormB into FormA.  You can load the individual form classes from FormB into FormA's mdi window, rather than into FormB's mdi window. If you can't do something like this, you could try to fake it by loading FormB without any window chrome, into the exact position over FormA.  I doubt this will work tho...  For example if the user moves FormA, FormB will be out of position.  They will both have entries in the task bar, and one is essentially shown on top of the other.

Comment: @Noel, for the last approach (*you could try to fake it by loading FormB without any window chrome*), can you show how to do it? Also, is there an approach where by FormB must always be contained inside FormA?

Comment: To be honest, im not sure how to do this with winforms, I think you can control the border style of the window, there is an enum somewhere on the form intance.  There is no approach I know of which will achieve exactly what you want.